# Start button won't alert() on VS code but works on Codepen

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to simply get my start button to give me an alert or console.log when it is clicked. However, this only works on Codepen when I try to test it out, but not on VS Code where I am building this. I don't know if it has something to do with bootstrap 4.

I have tried updating the bootstrap cdn and moving the bootstrap 4 scripts around

Javascript

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");

function alertButton(){
    alert("button was clicked");
    console.log("button was clicked");
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', alertButton);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pomodoro App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">   

                <h1 id="pom-header">Pomodoro App</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button id ="start" type="button" >Start</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <span id="timer">25</span>
    </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you putting that script in your HTML, if at all? I'm not as familiar with Codepen, but I know that others like JSFiddle wrap all JavaScript in an *on load* handler by default, which is **not** the behavior of a normal HTML document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are importing your JS file into your HTML. Down underneath where you import jQuery, put `<script src="/path/to/jsfile.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I did to get your click event to work. The script must be below the elemets you intend to add a click event to. Copy and paste it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>



    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pomodoro App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">   

                <h1 id="pom-header">Pomodoro App</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button id ="start" type="button" >Start</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <span id="timer">25</span>
    </div>



<script>
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start");

    function alertButton(){
        alert("button was clicked");
        console.log("button was clicked");
    }

    startButton.addEventListener('click', alertButton);
</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```